# Checkout to a local branch as detached a head

Tags: git

I'm trying to checkout to the latest commit of a git branch in the way that git thinks its detached. I cannot checkout to the branch itself because a [git worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) prevents this interaction, and bypassing this using the `-f`.

```
$ mkdir temp1
$ cd temp1
$ git init
$ echo a > test.txt
$ git add test.txt
$ git commit -m "Initial commit"
$ git worktree add ../temp2 --no-checkout
$ cd ../temp2
$ git checkout master
fatal: 'master' is already checked out at '../temp1'
```

While inside the "temp2" repository, I can checkout manually to the commit using its hash (`git checkout 392847`), I want to automate this without typing `git log`, copying the id, and then pasting it inside the git checkout command line.

Example what I want: (similar to a `git checkout origin/master` for repositories that contain pushed work):

```
$ git checkout <magic prefix> master
Note: checking out '<magic prefix>/master'.    

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental                                                
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this                                               
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.  

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may                                                
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:                                                                                                                                                                        

    git checkout -b <new-branch-name>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$ git checkout --detach master
```

This will effectively resolve the commit SHA1 of the master branch, then check it out as a detached HEAD. Alternative ways to do the same thing are `git checkout $(git rev-parse master)`, or the shorter `git checkout master^0`.

Alternatively, you could always create a new branch pointing to the same commit (`git checkout -b master-copy master`), or use a full clone (`git clone temp1 temp2`).

Comment: That would work for me, and is reasonably short enough for a shell function/custom git function, I will wait around 1 day before accepting, to let other people come up with their solutions

Comment: Looks like there is now also `git checkout --detach master`, does that work for you?

Comment: `--detach` also works for me, never knew that existed

Comment: `--detach` has [existed since Git 1.7.5](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5be1f00a9a701532232f57958efab4be8c959a29/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.5.txt#L34-L35) and is probably the way to go. Note that you can use the `^0` syntax as well, which is a little shorter than expanding the output of `git rev-parse`.

Comment: Creating a separate branch might be a good suggestion; creating a full clone probably isn't, since it means creating an unnecessary copy of the db and refs which could then fall out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is `git checkout --detach master`